# Is an English "OK" button acceptable for a Japanese-language dialog?

Tags: button, dialog, translation, cjk

Just a quick question about an English-to-Japanese software translation project:
I have seen many screenshots of dialog boxes in Japanese with a standard "OK" button.
is this normal, or would Japanese characters be more comfortable for Japanese users?

Comment: How is this about programming?

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, Microsoft seems perfectly happy with "OK" in a Japanese UI, according to their localization guide:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/b/3/4/b34f7185-afca-4846-8fbf-672a1b9afce2/jpn-jpn-styleguide.pdf

I'm not a native speaker of Japanese, but my personal experience as a student is that "OK" would be perfectly ordinary on a UI element. The Latin alphabet is widely used for borrowings in Japan, so it's not going to look strange to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

All Japanese people can read Latin characters. They take 6 years of compulsory English lessons in schools. They’re all familiar with basic English and even working class Japanese will say オケです. It’s essentially a loanword at this point. You can assume familiarity with this from a Japanese audience but you should be careful not to overuse English loanwords or it won’t read as “natural”.